# Can't see files after switching PCs

Tags: hard-drive, recycle-bin

I was using a separate HDD for most of my storage on a Windows 8.1 PC. I was going away so decided to take the HDD with me. I plugged it in another Windows 7 PC and kept adding more files to it.

Now upon my return when I plugged the HDD again to my original Windows 8.1 PC, it seems that all the new files that were created are gone. I kept getting an error message that the recyle bin is corrupted when I plugged the drive. And I used rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin to remove the error.

There is months of work that has been lost and some extremely important files. Is there any way I can get those back?

Comment: It was used as a secondary storage drive on both systems, right? If that's the case I don't see why all the files added via Win7 would disappear when you accessed the drive again via Win8. You can try common data recovery tools but it certainly is puzzling.

Comment: It was as a secondary drive on both. On the windows 7 PC it was one of the three drives. Any recommendations on recovery tools? I am willing to pay if something really works.

Comment: Recuva, TestDisk are free. Lots of paid ones too like R-Studio for example. For the paid ones try running them and if they detect most of your data then you can pay for them if you want to enable recovery. Most importantly *never* recover to the same drive.

Comment: I have tried all the different software but none are recovering the files that I need. I think the best possible way will be to undelete the Recyclye.bin file that I removed with the rd /s /q D:\$Recycle.bin command. And then undelete from the recycling bin.

But I don't know how to recover the deleted $Recycle.bin file. Any suggestions?

Comment: $Recycle.bin is a directory, not a file. If no software can recover the files then you're out of luck. If the files are very important to you then you can pay professionals to attempt a recovery.